# What are the different words for "beer"?

Tags: vocabulario, diferencias-regionales, comida

In Mexico, besides ***cerveza*** we call ***beer*** the following:

- cheve
- chela
- pisto (anything with alcohol)
- bironga
- helada
- fría

These are used informally.

Are there any other words used to address *beer* in Spanish in other countries?

Comment: Peruvian slangs for beer: chela, chilindrina, helada, helena, rubia

Comment: @Javi: *caña* confused me when I went to Spain, as *caña* in Argentina is another alcoholic drink, *Licor de caña (de azúcar)*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Spain it is very widespread to call it (colloquially) "[**birra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5atJF2Q)" (from the Italian *birra*, itself from the German *Bier*).

> Necesito una **birra**. (I need a beer) [slang]

You can also hear "**rubia**" for a lager. "Cerveza rubia" is the complete name, though informally some people call it just "rubia". The context of the sentence should make it clear you are referring to a lager beer instead of a blonde woman.

> ¿Me puedes poner una **rubia**? (Can I have a lager beer?).

And "**caña**" if it is a beer in a glass instead of in a bottle (which is called "botellín de cerveza" if it is small, "litrona" if it's a bottle of 1 litre). Also as Peter Taylor suggests (thanks) a third of a litre is called a "**tercio**" and you can use it to ask for 33cl of beer.

> Quiero una **caña**. (I want a glass of beer)
>
> Quiero una **botellín de cerveza**. (I want a bottle of beer)
>
> Quiero una **litrona** (de cerveza). (I want a litre bottle of beer)
>
> Quiero un **tercio** (de cerveza) (I want third of a litre of beer)

As MikMik points out there are some different names for the beer depending on the size of the glass. When the size of the glass is small (about 125 or 150cl) it is called in many ways, for example:

- **Corto**
- **Zurito** (name typical in the Basque Country)
- **Chato de cerveza**

the name "caña" is usually for a bigger glass.

As [MikMik](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/1139/different-words-for-beer#comment1968_1144) also points out "**garimba**" is another term used, at least [in the Canary Islands](http://www.lapalma.es/post/2009-11-09-nace-garimba-la-primera-cerveza-palmera).

Comment: Just a note: _caña_ refers to a normal serving of [keg beer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draught_beer#Keg_beer). But it is quite common to ask for "half servings" (about 125 or 150 cl.) which go by the names of _chato de cerveza_, _zurito_, _corto_ and others.

Comment: And another word I've heard for beer, though not very commonly, is _garimba_.

Comment: Not to mention *un tercio*, which while it could be a third of anything in principle, pragmatically is usually a third of a litre of beer.

Comment: I'd say that *tercio* is specifically 33cl **bottled** beer (you'd wouldn't expect 33cl of keg beer asking for a tercio). *Caña* is 20cl small glass of keg beer, *doble* is slightly bigger glass (40cl).

Comment: In Spain, in addition to all that has been mentioned, depending on the region and the size (and shape) of the glass, you have also **tubo**, **jarra**, **tanque**, **cañón** ("a big caña"), etc

Comment: Mini, a word used for the gigantic glasses of beer that were passed around by friends.

Comment: In parts of Spain (at least in Cataluña, I'm not sure about other regions), **quinto** is more common than **botellín** and **mediana** than **tercio**.

Answer (score 6):

In Chile and Mexico: [***Chela***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8gvyo1n):

> *¡Vamos por unas **Chelas**!*  →  Let's go for some beers!

Answer (score 4):

In Mexico beer is colloquially called in several different ways, here is a few ways I could think of off the top of my head:

- Chela
- Cheve
- Caguama
- caguamon
- Caguabonga
- Milonga (because of miller lites)
- Una fria 
  -Una birria (because of the close sound to beer)
- Una Muerta
- Una Kawasaki
- Una ballena (in areas near the coast)
- Una amarga
- Un carton
- Un sixto
- Una heladia
- El pisto
- el chupe
- Unas serpientes
- Unas cachetonas de banqueta

That is all I could think of for now.

Comment: quite a lot of them! Do you know why do they call it _una kawasaki_ for exaple? Or _el chupe_?

Comment: Hello there, Kawasaki is derived form the word caguama because it sounds alike.

Comment: And chupe because the Mexican colloquial expression for drinking alcoholic beverages is chupar, which actually means to suck, but colloquially it means to drink alcoholic beverages, so that's where chupe comes from. Caguama on the other hand, is a big beer bottle, although any type or size of beer can be a caguama. Caguama comes from the name of the caguama turtle, which is a gigantic turtle; the equivalent to caguama in American English would be a 40, which refers to a forty ounce beer bottle.

Comment: this is specially cool. I will ask different questions so that this info shines into specific answers

Comment: I asked a question on this: [¿Por qué se llama “chupe” a la cerveza en México?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/28685/1674)

Answer (score 3):

Colombia:

- Birra
- Birrincha
- Pola
- Amargas

Comment: ¿En cuál lugar de Colombia usan las expresiones "birra" y "birrincha"?

Comment: @alvalongo "birra" en cualquier lugar se entiende, creo yo. "Birrincha" creo que más que la región, tiene más que ver la edad de la persona y su grado de sofisticación ;)

Comment: no respondió, en que región de Colombia usan "birra" y "birrincha"? Nunca las he oido

Answer (score 3):

In Spain we mostly use "birra" and "caña" (besides "cerveza").

- **Birra** It's used like "cerveza", but it's more casual.
- **Caña** Usually it's a beer from the tap, not a can or a bottle.

Answer (score 3):

In Chile, we call a big glass of beer a *shop*. This is attested even by serious newspapers (e.g. [here](http://finde.latercera.com/bares/dia-de-la-cerveza-chile-2018/)). It is not uncommon to hear Chileans say "vamos por un shop".

From this word is where a "famous" drink derives, the *fanshop* (a mixture of Fanta and beer).

Comment: I wonder if this word comes from the German word "Schoppen", which is a quarter liter of beer or wine (or cider). (There is also the French "chopine".)

Answer (score 2):

In Cuba, [***lagarto***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MnrWCnQ) or [***láguer***](https://ruc.udc.es/dspace/bitstream/handle/2183/8201/LYT_20_2003_art_12.pdf) (generic term for a beer, unlike English *lager*).

In Catalonia, [***quinto***](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UvNPWWd) (historically a *fifth* of a litre) is used to refer to any small bottle of beer (250ml usually).

In Mexico you also have [***caguama*** and ***ballena***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_bottle#%22Caguama%22_and_%22Ballena%22_bottles) (940 ml bottle).

Answer (score 2):

In Mexico I have additionally encountered

- **amarga** - literally, 'a bitter'; used in a similar fashion to **una fria**, 'a cold one'
- **chevecha** - dated, less commonly used