# ¿Por qué se llama "chupe" a la cerveza en México?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, coloquialismos, méxico, comida

En la pregunta [What are the different words for "beer"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1139/1674) hay una respuesta que da un listado grande de palabras usadas para llamar a la cerveza en México.

Entre ellas me llamó la curiosidad una: ***la chupe***.

El DLE tiene unas entradas para esta palabra:

> [**chupe<sup>1</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=94nUYqA)
>   *De chupar.*
>
> 1. m. And. chupador (‖ pieza para que chupen los niños).
>
> [**chupe<sup>2</sup>**](https://dle.rae.es/?id=94ow6xJ)
>   *Del quechua chupi 'sopa'.*
>
> 1. m. Arg., Bol., Col., Ec., Pan., Perú y Ven. Guisado hecho de papas en caldo, al que se le añade carne o pescado, mariscos, huevos, ají, tomates y otros ingredientes.
> 2. m. Ven. Sopa hecha con caldo de gallina, pollo o camarones al que se le añade leche, granos de maíz, trocitos de papa y queso.

Y luego el DAMER tiene un montón, también en la línea de la sopa quechúa:

> [**chupe**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=t2SDF7nb7x0AeBX61hw).
>
> I.    1.  m. Mx, Ar, Ur; Ho, juv. Bebida alcohólica. pop + cult → espon.
>   2.  Mx, Ar, Ur. Consumo de bebidas alcohólicas. pop + cult → espon.
>   3.  m. Ec. juv. Fiesta en la que se consumen bebidas alcohólicas en exceso. pop.
>
> II. (Del quech. chupí, sopa).
>   1.  m. Pa, Co, Pe, Bo:C,O. Guisado hecho de papas en caldo, al que se le añade carne o pescado, mariscos, huevos, ají, tomates y otros ingredientes.
>   2.  Ar:NO. Caldo espeso hecho con leche o agua, papa, carne, choclos y otros ingredientes.
>   3.  Ve. Sopa hecha con caldo de gallina, pollo o camarones al que se le añaden leche, granos de maíz, trocitos de papa y queso.
>   4.  Ch. Guiso hecho con pan, queso y otros ingredientes al que se le añaden carne, mariscos o pescado.
>   5.  Pa. Sopa muy espesa hecha a base de ñame y carne de res o pescado.
>
> III.
>   1.  sust/adj. Pe. Empleado que ocupa un cargo de poca importancia.
>   2.  Pe. chupamedias.
>
> IV.
>   1.  m. ES. Aspiración del humo de un cigarrillo.
>
> V.
>   1.  m. Ur. Malhumor, enojo. pop + cult → espon.
>   ■
>   a. ǁ    ~ de viernes. m. Pe. Chupe de papas en caldo con pescado, habitual en Cuaresma y Semana Santa.
>
> [**¡chupe!**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=ymnoY4M4rx0AzE5Wc8S)
>
> I.    1.  interj. Co. Expresa satisfacción por algo malo que le sucede a alguien.

¿Por qué se utiliza esta palabra? ¿Es usada estrictamente en México y en ambiente coloquial? Dado que el quechua se habla en la zona del Perú, no creo que su etimología haya influido en la palabra en Méxicio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Chupe* (masculino, *el chupe*) se utiliza, como ves en el DAMER, como sinónimo de (consumo de) bebidas alcohólicas en varios países, desde México hasta Argentina (acá también decimos *chupi*). No parece ser que se trate de un derivación del quechua (en el caso de México esto sería, como notaste, muy poco probable), sino que es, como dice el DAMER, una creación espontánea.

En Argentina al menos, el verbo *chupar* significa coloquialmente "consumir bebidas alcohólicas", y se usa de hecho más que el sustantivo correspondiente *chupe*. Siempre entendí que era una asociación entre la idea de "absorber" y la de "beber mucho" (por eso a veces se completa la frase relativa al consumo de alcohol con un "...como una esponja"). El uso de *chupe* como "guiso" sí está restringido al noroeste de Argentina, justamente la región que sufrió la mayor influencia quechua, tal como se esperaría.

Comment: Exactamente lo mismo aplica para Colombia. +1